# Perm gen growing up

Tags: java, memory-management, jvm, jsf-1.2, java-6

I have recently discovered the following facts:

The first time I navigate through pages of my application, perm gem is growing up significantly. (That's normal)

My perm gen is growing up when I am navigating through pages of my application that I have already navigated through. 
But this is only happening if I stop using my application for a few minutes. If I don't do that perm gen remains the same though I keep navigating.
The increase is not much but I think is not a normal behaviour.

I also noticed that perm gen never goes down or It goes down a little bit.

What can be the cause of that?

I am using Java6, Tomcat6, Hibernate, Spring 3.3.4 and JSF 1.2.

Answer (score 0):

PermGen errors and leaks are tricky to investigate.

To deal with them, them, the first thing you can do is to check you statics. Your application can manage some statics that are holding references to objects that should have been garbage collected but are still marked as reachable because are referenced by the these statics.

For example, you are using Spring, and in Spring, beans are Singleton by default so it can be a source of PermGen problems.

To know more about the objects in memory you can use some profiling tools, such as [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/). It can help you to investigate how many instances of a given class is holding Tomcat, and it can give you a clue about where the leak can be.

To learn more about the PermGen and PermGen errors and issues you can look at [The java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen Space error demystified](http://file:///E:/Downloads/Presentation%20from%20Sun%20about%20java%20memory%20leaks.pdf)